# Spring Batch step configuration: infinite loop

Tags: configuration, spring-batch, infinite-loop, step

everyone.
I'm using Spring Batch.
I have a job composed of 3 step: Step1, Step2, Step3.
With these 3 steps I configured a loop of this kind:

```
      +--> Step1 --> Step2 --> Step3 --+
      |                                |
      +--------------------------------+
```

I want to execute this loop for 3 times.

At the end of the 1st iteration, Spring Batch has an instance of the execution of each step: each step execution instance has a status BatchStatus.COMPLETED and an exit status ExitStatus.COMPLETED.

During the 2nd iteration, the Step1 completes successfully; the Step2 fails.

Now, if I try to re-run the job, Spring Batch does not execute Step1: it's COMPLETED; so it executes Step2. Step2 completes successfully and now the problem arises: Spring Batch does not execute Step3: there is a step execution instance of Step3 in db that is COMPLETED (that one created after the 1st iteration); at the same time it does note execute Step1 for an analogous reason. So it executes Step2 in an infinite loop!

What can I do? I would like that at the 2nd attempt of executing the job, after the Step2, the Step3 is executed, and then the Step1 and so on.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't see this as an issue. How did you configured the flow to loop for 3 times? Have you set the `allowStartIfComplete` on your steps? Please share the code of a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to reproduce the infinite loop.

Comment: This is a big issue, because the step can't be restartable after they complete: in every iteration, some computations are made on a particular subject (a company!).
The first iteration completes for the first company.
the second iteration (for the second company) fails on Step2. A bug is fixed (!), the job is re-launched, the computation restarts from the Step2 for the 2nd company, but the 3th step for the 2nd company is not executed: a Step3 (COMPLETED FOR THE 1ST COMPANY!) exists as COMPLETED!

Comment: I thought that Spring Batch executes a step leveraging on the state of the job context: in my case, for every company a particular context exists, different for every company!!

Comment: Well, if `for every company a particular context exists`, then you need a different execution context for each company, which means a different job/step execution for each company, which in turn means a different job instance per company, which finally as you might have guessed it means, the company should be a job parameter. With this approach, a failed job execution for one company is not mixed with another company. So much complexity in software comes from trying to make one thing do two (or more) things.

Comment: Mahmoud, I thank you for your response and suggestion, but i's not possible to configure a job for each company. In these days I had to remove loops to avoid related issues.